# Select with grouping by year and month with special order

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, group-by

I have an `events` table with rows, each having `schedule` datetime column like this:

```
---------------------------------------
|  id   |     schedule          | .....
---------------------------------------
|  234  |  2014-06-18 15:53:00  | .....
|   23  |  2014-06-11 08:02:00  | .....
|    1  |  2014-06-28 20:09:00  | .....
|  122  |  2014-06-24 07:54:00  | .....
|  125  |  2014-07-16 06:45:00  | .....
|  456  |  2014-07-06 08:24:00  | .....
|   54  |  2014-07-10 09:39:00  | .....
|    2  |  2014-08-02 19:08:00  | .....
|    8  |  2014-09-25 01:50:24  | .....
|   45  |  2014-09-04 08:41:51  | .....
```

All rows are in random order.

I need to write select statement, that will produce results in such way:

```
------------------------------
| id  |   schedule   |
-----------------------------
|  23 |  2014-06-11  |
| 456 |  2014-07-06  |
|   2 |  2014-08-02  |
|  45 |  2014-09-04  |
```

That is:

1) the result set should contain only ONE entry for each month;

2) each date should be the smallest one for that month, that is if we have `2014-07-02` and `2014-07-24` (all dates are in random order initially), the only entry that should be present in result set for this month should be `2014-07-02`, that is the smallest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this query:

```
SELECT events.*
FROM
  events INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(schedule) min_schedule
                     FROM events
                     GROUP BY YEAR(schedule), MONTH(schedule)) m
  ON events.schedule = m.min_schedule
ORDER BY
  events.schedule
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1749a2/1). The subquery will calculate the minimun schedule date for each month, then I'm joining back the events table with the minimun schedule date for every months.

Comment: Good answer, so I'll select this one as it was published first and is more pretty. Thanx

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use a subquery to get the minimums for each month, and then join back to the main table using that.  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b94f1f/10)

```
select
table1.`id`,
table1.`schedule`
from
table1
inner join 
(
select
(year(`schedule`) * 100) + month(`schedule`) as prd,
min(`schedule`) as schedule
from
table1
group by

(year(`schedule`) * 100) + month(`schedule`)) mins
on table1.`schedule` = mins.`schedule`
```

Comment: Why do you use `year(schedule) * 100`? What is the purpose of `* 100` part?

Comment: just to combine the year and month in a single field, so that June 2014 will be 201406.